# how to get most popular articles from model and order desc

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a little problem in my laravel 5.2 project.

i want to get popular articles, most visited ones and order by DESC.
this is my controller code.

```
public function trending(){
    $trends = DB::table('articles')->orderBy('hits', 'DESC')->get();
    return view('frontend.index', compact('trends'))
```

this is not displaying any value.. and my laravel says undefined variable $trends.

```
@foreach($trends as $trend)
<li>

       <a href="#"><img class="photo" src="uploads/thumbs/{{ $trend->image }}" width="90px" height="90px"/></a>

                <h2><a href="{{ route('single.show',$article->slug) }}">{{ $trend->title }}</a></h2>

                <div class="date">{{date('M j, Y h:ia', strtotime($trend->created_at))}}</div>
            </li>
@endforeach
```

{{ trends}} variable is not holding any value..

Comment: I assume in your actual code the `return` line has a semi-colon at the end? If not, I would do that first.

Comment: Yeah. sorry there is semiclon at the end of that return line as usual.

Comment: `return view('frontend.index', compact('trends'))` needs a semi colon at the end of it.

Comment: Yeah. i have that semi colon.at the end of that return.return view('frontend.index', compact('trends'));

Comment: what do you get if you add 'dump($trends); in your function trending()
just to make sure the db query works.
add it between the two lines (before return and after DB::table...)

Comment: @flynorc when i give this its own function like trending it is not returning any value. but i came up with a little solution know i added this code in my index function . and it is working. but why it is not working when i make trending function. this is the code that working .    public function index(){
        $trends = DB::table('articles')->orderBy('hits', 'DESC')->get();
        $articles = DB::table('articles')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
        return view('frontend.index', compact('articles', 'trends'));
    } .

Comment: Are you calling the correct method of the controller in your routes? (add some debug text that you can identify that you are indeed in the method you think you are)
Is the data beeing fetched from the database (add dump($articles) or dump($trends))
is the data passed to the view correctly, add the dump in the view {{dump($articles)}}

Answer (score 0):

First check $trends have value or not.

@if(count($trends) > 0)
  @foreach($trends as $trend)
   ...
   ...
  @endforeach
@endif

And run above query in phpmyadmin and check what is return.